# how to properly call google closure strContains

Tags: closures, google-closure, google-closure-library, google-closure-templates

When I try to compile soy template containing this closure code

```
 {if  strContains($field, "date") }
```

This is the error

> com.google.template.soy.base.SoySyntaxException:
>   Not all code is in Soy V2 syntax (found tag {if strContains($field, "date")} not in Soy V2 syntax).

Am I missing something here?
I compiled the the soy template using this command

> java -jar SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar --outputPathFormat templates.js templates.soy

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: {if  strContains($field, 'date') } single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Soy templates use single quoted strings. So replace "date" with 'date'.